# Windows AD authentication to local user

Tags: windows-7, authentication, active-directory, winlogon

I want to use AD to authenticate users for some lab PCs but then I want them to be logged into a shared local profile.

I don't want to use roaming profiles and I don't want to wait approx 30 secs for an account to be created for each user who logs into the the lab PC (hence pointing them at a shared local account)

Any ideas?

Comment: This is mor like a serverfault question